# Creating serial numbers based on a group unique id in 2 columns

Tags: r, serialization, group-by, dplyr

I have this data

```
cluster<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
structure<-c(1,1,2,3,1,1,1,2)
str<-data.frame(clusters,structures)
```

i want to create a third column called serial numbers based on the cluster and structure. this is in such a way that i get the following output

```
serial.number<-c(1,2,1,1,1,2,3,1)
str2<-data.frame(cluster,structure,serial.number)
```

thankyou

Comment: str$serial.number<-c(1,2,1,1,1,2,3,1) will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      group_by(cluster, structure) %>%
      mutate(serial.number = row_number())
```

---

or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, serial.number := rowid(cluster, structure)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ave` + `seq_along` if you are with base R

```
within(str, serial.number <- ave(structure,cluster,FUN = seq_along))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this:

```
library(data.table)
df <- setDT(str)
df[, serial.number := seq(.N), by = .(cluster,structure)]
```

Comment: works perfectly, but is there an alternative, without using data.table?

Comment: probably there is an alternative, but I use datatable on purpose. Is there a reason you don't want to use datatable?